# Virtual keyboard turn portrait to landscape mode

Tags: landscape-portrait, virtual-keyboard, mobile-browser, android-virtual-keyboard

I have a site that changes its layout depending on the orientation of the device. However, when there is a form in the page and the user focus on the text field, the virtual keyboard will pops up and turn the page to "landscape mode" (probably triggered by the lower height of the page)

I noticed this problem in Chrome, Firefox and Dolphin mobile browsers, is there any way to make the browser stays in portrait when the device IS portrait?